# nested "select " query in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

hi i am executing nested "select" query in mysql .
the query is

```
SELECT `btitle` FROM `backlog` WHERE `bid` in (SELECT  `abacklog_id`  FROM `asprint` WHERE `aid`=184 )
```

I am not getting expected answer by the above query. If I execute:

SELECT  `abacklog_id`  FROM `asprint` WHERE `aid`=184

separately

I will get abacklog_id as `42,43,44,45`;

So if again I execute:

```
SELECT `btitle` FROM `backlog` WHERE `bid` in(42,43,44,45)
```

I will get btitle as    `scrum1 scrum2 scrum3 msoffice`

But if I combine those queries I  will get only `scrum1` remaining  3 `atitle` will not get.

Comment: Try `JOIN`: `SELECT b.ab_title FROM age_backlog b INNER JOIN  age_sprint s ON b.ab_id = s.as_backlog_id WHERE s.as_id=184`

Comment: Your query looks fine...42,43,44,45 in a single col value or on multiple row valuw

Comment: ya i tried with joins also still the same answer

Comment: @ swapnesh its multiple row value

Comment: Is age_backlog.AB_ID string while as_backLog_Id is numeric  or vice-versa?

Comment: @ xQbert yes  age_backlog.ab_id  is int and age_sprin.as_backLog_Id is varchar .

Comment: So you're trying to do an "in" on different data types.  Wouldn't one need to be cast to the other data type in order for the 'in' to resolve?  Or does mysql automatically do an implicit conversion on these for you; forgive me, I don't know mysql casting rules well enough.  in other words 1 <> '1'  or 1 !='1' in all cases; some engines depending on use will not do the conversion for you.

Comment: @ xQbert thanks for suggestion  .even i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try As Like Following...

```
SELECT `age_backlog`.`ab_title` FROM `age_backlog` LEFT JOIN `age_sprint` ON `age_backlog`.`ab_id` = `age_sprint`.`as_backlog_id` WHERE `age_sprint`.`as_id` = 184
```

By using this query you will get result with loop . You will be able to get all result with same by place with comma separated by using IMPLODE function ..

May it will be helpful for you... If you get any error , Please inform me...

Comment: @ Maruf Hossain                                                    if i execute above query  i will not get any result.just it will display as follows . "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )"

Answer (score 0):

What you did is to store comma separated values in `age_sprint.as_backlog_id`, right?

Your query actually becomes

```
SELECT `ab_title` FROM `age_backlog` WHERE `ab_id` IN ('42,43,44,45')
```

Note the `'` in the `IN()` function. You don't get separate numbers, you get one string.

Now, when you do

```
SELECT CAST('42,43,44,45' AS SIGNED)
```

which basically is the implicit cast MySQL does, the result is `42`. That's why you just get `scrum1` as result.

You can search for dozens of answers to this problem here on SO.

You should never ever store comma separated values in a database. It violates the first normal form. In most cases databases are in third normal form or BCNF or even higher. Lower normal forms are just used in some special cases to get the most performance, usually for reporting issues. Not for actually working with data. You want 1 row for every `as_backlog_id`.

Again, your primary goal should be to get a better database design, not to write some crazy functions to get each comma separated number out of the field.

Comment: Author's comment indicated to swapnesh that "its multiple row value" you may be right but this comment leads me down a different path.